# Generating letter by its position in the alphabet

Tags: excel

I want a formula that can return the letter of the excel alphabet (27 = AA etc.) of a given number.

The purpose of this is that I have a table that returns values in a spreadsheet. I am summarizing data of climate measurements in cities, this data takes up 4 columns (but the same rows and relative positions in each column, so I29 and J29 contain 2  numbers I need, and then  M29 and N29 contain the same data for the next location.

I want to create a summary table that looks like the below

```
City     Rainfall Average      Sunshine Average
City A   =I29                      =J29
City B   =M29                      =N29
City C etc.
```

my problem is that i go up to a few hundred cities, and i want to be able to populate the cells automatically/fill down. I know what row the data is in but need to generate the column letters using the formula requested above, so I can use a concatenate to create the cell reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`ADDRESS`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/address-HP005208983.aspx) function.

For example, `=ADDRESS(29,27)` will return the string "$AA$29".

---

However, honestly in your situation I would use the `OFFSET` function, combined with `ROW()`. To illustrate, let's say your table starts with a header row on row 50 and data starts on row 51. The data for a given city would start `(ROW() - 51) * 4` columns to the right of `I29`. So:

```
      A               B                      C
50  City     Rainfall Average                Sunshine Average
51  City A   =OFFSET($I$29,0,(ROW()-51)*4)   =OFFSET($I$29,0,(ROW()-51)*4+1)
52  City B   =OFFSET($I$29,0,(ROW()-51)*4)   =OFFSET($I$29,0,(ROW()-51)*4+1)
53  City C   etc.
```

Of course, you have to be careful if you want to move these cells around; you'll have to change the `51`.